# Other users receive messages

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

So this is not an error. I just don't know how to do this.
 I created a chat application with HTML/JS/PHP and I am storing the messages for each chat in a mysql database. I am currently using a php script to receive all messages from the database every 0.5 seconds and printing them onto my chat file. I wanted to know any better way to receive a message without having to reload or wait. Maybe some kind of notification the if a person sent a message then the other users of the chat receive that exact message or some socket thing idk. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using WebSockets. Check this out - https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

Answer (score 0):

Websockets is the best way to do this. This opens a constant connection to the server and the server can push events to the client.

With php this can be implemented by using another service like [Redis](https://redis.io/) or [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

By using this you don't have to pull the data from the server continuously.